# Buildr include jar files

Tags: buildr

I have an old project with files layout still in "src/" and jars in "lib/". I defined the layout to point to src.

`compile.with(Dir[_("lib/*.jar")])`

But when I run `buildr build`, it still stays `package <name> does not exist`.
How can I resolve this?
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to debug this for yourself by adding a line:

```
puts Dir[_("lib/*.jar")]
```

You might want to use Dir[_("lib/**/*.jar")] in case there are jars in subdirectories.